# Is <div id="xssstring">{!untrustedData }</div> is having XSS issue?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have div like  `<div id="xssstring">{!untrustedData }</div>`   and related controller   variable as    `String  untrustedData = '</div><script>alert(1)</script><div>';`   now salesforce says this can cause XSS so need to use HTMLENCODE.  But when I am passing the above   string to VF page  the javascript is not getting executed so I don't feel it is XSS. Can anybody help me to understand this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is a cross-site scripting (XSS) issue. If you inspect the output html you will find that the `untrustedData` string is not coming out as:

```
</div><script>alert(1)</script><div>
```

Instead its getting encoding and will come out like:

`&lt;/div&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;&lt;div&gt;`

The `alert` is not happening because it has been encoded and is no longer javascript. SalesForce are telling you to use `HTMLENCODE` so that HTML and Javascript can not be injected into your page. If an end user was able to alter the `untrustedData` variable then they can add any javascript they want to your page.

You could also document why your code is currently doing this and why its an acceptable vulnerability, which SalesForce should be ok with when you do a security review.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an XSS issue because the platform auto-encodes the merge-field for you. You don't need to do anything here.

I'm not sure what you mean by "salesforce says this can cause XSS" -- dev support, the checkmarx scanner, or a security review? But feel free to book an office hour and discuss this with the security team.

On the other hand, this does not mean that your code is XSS free. For example, the following has an XSS vuln despite salesforce auto-encoding.

```
<div id="xssstring">{!untrustedData }</div> <!-- safe, because auto-encoded
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('xssstring');
el.innerHTML = '<b>' + el.outerText + '</b>'; //now vulnerable because of innerHTML
</script>
```